# ~80% discrepancy in disk space/size installing Pop!_OS

Tags: partition, ssd

I'm baffled by this one. I'm trying to install Pop!_OS 19.10 and I have a significant discrepancy.

You can see in these two pictures (sorry for the poor quality, need to click on them to make them larger to see what I'm talking about), one with preexisting partitions and one with the drive clean, that there is a ~80% discrepancy in size between the front and back windows during install.

The problem is I have a 850MB EFI, well above the minimum 500MB, and it says it is too small because it shows as like 111.4MB and then can't install the OS.

When the drive is clean, it shows its total size as 512.1GB, when it is actually 3.73TB (shown on the front window).

Formatting partitions as ext4.

Drive is tested and works fine in Windows 10, macOS 10.14.5, Ubuntu 19.10. Just only happens with Pop!_OS.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions as to what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your NVMe SSD might be using 4096 byte block size instead of the classic 512 byte size, and the main installer (the back window) cannot take that into account, but the GParted partitioning tool (the front window) can.

The difference is not exactly 8x because the installer reports the disk size in SI-style unit prefixes (1 GB = 1000^3 bytes) while GParted uses powers-of-two based prefixes (1 GiB = 1024^3 bytes).

You might want to file a bug report on the Pop!_OS installer.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I do recall changing the block size to 4096. This came out of a former Hackintosh and one of the recommended steps was to change the block size to 4096 because "macOS have native support and works better with 4k blocks". I'll open a ticket because this is definitely wrong.

Comment: Yeah, and the support for 4k blocks is only going to become more and more important in the near future.